# Preg_match help find tag and match internal

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to do a `preg_match` for `data-movie="???"` to retrieve the `???`.

`preg_match('/data-movie="(.*?)"/is',$results,$m);`

I can't quite get it right.

Comment: Can you give an example of what's in your `$results` variable? So what data you're trying to match against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the movie will always be enclosed in double quotes, this works:

```
preg_match('/data-movie="([^"]*)"/is', $results, $m);
```

It keeps matching any character until a `"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/data\-movie="(.*)"/is', 'data-movie="abcdef"', $result);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => data-movie="abcdef"
    [1] => abcdef
)
```

This might help you too: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Comment: That sort fo works. It is not stoping after the next " it is going to the end. How can I make it look for the next " after data-movie="?

Comment: @ATLChris Changing the (.*) to (.*?) would make this work by making the regex ungreedy (stops matching at the first `"` instead of the last).